# How to modify the default hard disk location of a cloned vm in oracle vm virtualbox?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, virtualization, filemanager, oracle

Need help to change the default location of cloned vm hard disk in oracle vm virtualbox, by default it's saved now in "/root/VirtualBox VMs/server Clone/server Clone.vdi".

Help me to change this location. TIA..

My host machine is Ubuntu 14.04 server.

Comment: I believe you simply move it with `mv /root/Virtual\ VMs/server\ Clone` to new location and __add it__ from VIrtualBox

Comment: When I select the clone option, it's not giving me any option about the hard disk location. 
It's always going to the default location  I need to change that settings in oracle vm virtualbox.

Comment: Yes I also don't see that there so I guess the command line is the last resort..

Comment: Got the solution, we can change the default machine folder by selecting `Preferences`  from the the `File` menu in the VirtualBox main window. Then in the window that pops up on the `General` tab. Here change the `Default Machine Folder`.
Alternatively, can use 
`VBoxManage setproperty machinefolder;`
for more information check this link:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-setproperty

Comment: Ok if that's what u wanted I knew that but taught you wanted separate folder for clones!

Comment: From the command line: `VirtualManager clonevm --name  openSUSE-Leap  --basefolder /path/to/new/location`

Comment: getting this error `VirtualManager: command not found` @George
My host is Ubuntu 14.04 server

Comment: Sorry its `VBoxManage clonevm --name openSUSE-Leap --basefolder /path/to/new/location`

Comment: Find the name using `VBoxManage list vms` to list ure VMs

Comment: I just want to modify a little on your first command`VBoxManage clonevm registered-vm-name --name openSUSE-Leap --basefolder /path/to/new/location` .

From `VBoxManage list vms`  we can list out the registered vm names, great you don't miss that also. 
all things are correct now, your command is the answer if I use cli.
Thanks man.@George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they added the ability to specify a path in the GUI too (added in 6.0 if I'm not mistaken):

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#clone

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To be able to clone a VirtualBox device to another location other than the default one do the following in a terminal:

1. Get a list of the `registered names` of your virtual devices:

   ```
   VBoxManage list vms
   ```
2. Using the name from step one, clone and move to desire location:

   ```
   VBoxManage clonevm <registered-vm-name> --name <new-vm-name>  --register --basefolder /path/to/new/location
   ```

More information:

```
--name: name of virtualbox machine
--register: Automatically register the new clone in this VirtualBox installation
--basefolder: Folder where the new virtual machine configuration should be saved in.
```

Source:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonevm